# file_exists on Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a web page that lists thousands of links to image files. Currently the way this is handled is with a very large HTML file that is manually edited with the name of the image and links to the image file. The images aren't managed very well so often many of the links are broken or the name is wrong.

Here is an example of one line of the thousands of lines in the HTML file:

```
    <h4>XL Green Shirt<h4>
<h5>SKU 158f15 </h5>
    [<a href="http://website.com/images/products/TIFF/158f15.tif" target="_blank">TIFF</a>] 
    [<a href="http://website.com/images/products/158f15.jpg" target="_blank">JPEG</a>]
    [<a href="http://website.com/images/products/PNG/158f15.png" target="_blank">PNG</a>]
    <br />
```

I have the product information about the images in a database, so my solution was to write a page in PHP to iterate through each of the product numbers in the database and see if a file existed with the same id and then display the appropriate link and information.

I did this with the PHP function file_exists() since the product id is the same as the file name, and it worked fine on my local machine. The problem is all the images are hosted on AmazonS3, so running this function thousands of times to S3 always causes the request to time out. I've tried similar PHP functions as well as pinging the URL and testing for a 200 or 404 response, all time out.

Is there a solution that can check the existence of a file on a remote URL and consume few resources? Or is there a more novel way I can attack this problem?

Comment: Is it your own S3 account?  If so, surely there are API calls you can use to discover this information.

Comment: I think you should store in your database if an image has been uploaded for this product, if possible

Comment: It is my own account, but I am new to S3, so if there are I'm not aware of them.

Comment: @albresas that would change the process in which files are uploaded to S3 (currently using a firefox plugin), as all images are uploaded internally. though I am not ruling out this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better served to make sure you enforce the existence of a file upon placing the record in the database than trying to check for the existence of thousands of files on each and every page load.

That being said, an alternate solution would possibly to use `s3fs` with local storage cache directory within which to check for existence of the file. This would be much faster than checking your S3 storage directly. `s3fs` would also provide a convenient way to write new files into the S3 storage.